# Keyup not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I have been working with the Keyup method of jQuery and it doesn't seem to work for me. I went to create this on Jfiddle and sure enough it works there. But when upload it to a website or run it locally it does not work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('#TAcomments').keyup(function() {
        var textCount = $(this).val().length;
        if(textCount <= 10) {
          $('#TAcomments').stop().animate({ fontSize : '22px' });
        }
        if(textCount > 10) {
          $('#TAcomments').stop().animate({ fontSize : '16px' });
        }
        if(textCount > 20) {
          $('#TAcomments').stop().animate({ fontSize : '14px' });
        }
        if(textCount > 30) {
          $('#TAcomments').stop().animate({ fontSize : '10px' });
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="TAcomments" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; font-size: 22px;"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why so much copy and paste action to change one value? Use a variable. `$('#TAcomments').stop().animate({ fontSize : theValue });` And use `else if`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait until the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#TAcomments').keyup(function() {
        var textCount = $(this).val().length;
        if(textCount <= 10) {
            $('#TAcomments').stop().animate({ fontSize : '22px' }); 
        }
        if(textCount > 10) {
           $('#TAcomments').stop().animate({ fontSize : '16px' });               
        }
        if(textCount > 20) {
           $('#TAcomments').stop().animate({ fontSize : '14px' });   
        }
        if(textCount > 30) {
           $('#TAcomments').stop().animate({ fontSize : '10px' });   
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle defaults to running code after the onload event.

Comment: Awesome Thanks! Why is this required to run after the document is ready?

Comment: Because the HTML might not be properly loaded yet ... So basically there might be a race condition wherein the event is being defined when the element is not available in the DOM yet..

Comment: If you don't wait until the document is ready, the code can only see elements that were in the dom above the script tag. For example, in this case you would only be able to target "head", "html", "title", or the script nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the code in the script in `$(function () { /* ... */ });`  You can see that the code works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vRrjH/1) when it is ran in `onDomReady`.